# How to call Controller Action on standart html event in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Common question is: how to call Controller.Action and send it some parameters on standard html event (like `onblur` or `onclick`).

I`m using Asp.Net MVC3.

Original situation:
I have DropDownList on my page like this:

`@Html.DropDownList("DropDownList", ViewBag.selectList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)`

I dont want to use `@Html.DropDownListFor` because it means I should save some additional information in my model which is unlikely.

What I need: to call `DropDownListSelectionChanged(int moduleId)` action of the same controller `SelectedIndexChanged` event and to send Selected Item Value to this action.

Please, help.

Comment: Do you want a full page post or ajax?

Comment: Either Ajax or even just Get request (i know it sounds strange to call for a new page on SelectedIndexChanged).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty simple. You can either use the built in `Ajax.BeginForm` in MVC land, or you can use jQuery to send the request. I'll show you the jQuery example (simply because jQuery makes ajax stupidly easy and it's easy to write):

```
 $('#myDropDownIdAttribute').change(function()
 {
     $.ajax({
        url: 'Some/ActionName', // SomeController, ActionName
        data: { selectedValue: $(this).val() },
        success: function()
        {
           // Success Callback
        }
     });
 });
```

Then your action method would look like this:

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string selectedValue)
{
    // Do Stuff
}
```